# What is the meaning of "someone has pivoted"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, verbs

What is the meaning of pivot in this sentence:

> We do see companies that, literally, every time we meet them, they've **pivoted**. Every time, they're off to something new, and it's like watching a rabbit go through a maze or something.
>
> Source: [Business Insider, *Lessons from Marc Andressen*](http://www.businessinsider.com/business-lessons-from-marc-andreessen-2016-12?op=1%2F&r=UK&IR=T#-2)

What is the meaning of *someone is pivoted*?

Comment: Because this is your first question, I've taken the liberty to add some more details. You may want to read through [this meta question](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source) to learn more about why background information (such as the source of the quote and additional surrounding context) is so crucial when asking a question like this one. Not every idiom is readily understandable from a single sentence.

Comment: The example uses "They have pivoted" not "someone is pivoted". Please [edit] your question to match the quote.

Comment: @JamesK - I don't think that edit is necessary; I think it reveals some pertinent information (namely, that the OP assumed that this was a standard idiom that could apply to individuals).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the phrase is not ***is*** pivoted but ***has*** pivoted; and compare this definition in [Oxford dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pivot)

> 1. Turn on or as if on a pivot.
>      *‘he swung round, pivoting on his heel’*

Andressen is thus saying that the companies he speaks of change direction constantly, even abruptly—they don't give their business plans the time required to mature.

> They're never going to converge on anything because they're never going to put the time into actually figuring it out and getting it right.

Note that Andreesen is scornful of the common use of *pivot* among businessfolk as a term of praise: "pivoting" for them demonstrates "agility", the ability to respond swiftly and easily to new situations and opportunities.

> . . . when I first started out, we didn't have the word 'pivot.' We didn't have a fancy word for it. We just called it a f---up.